# Can't See TextView in Xcode Simulator Storyboard after building

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a screen that contains a multiple line `TextView`
I put some constrains on the `TextView` to make it in the middle of the screen'such as:"
Align Center x to superview
Align center y to superview
Align Trailing to Sage Area 20
Align Leading to Safe Area 20
and when I build it for the simulator for iPhone X
I can not see the `TextView` on the screen
what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

My Screen>

[image]

My Constrains>

[image]

Comment: Check for **isHidden** property is **true** anywhere or the **height constraint** for textView is missing.

Comment: Checked, and there is Height constraint for the textview

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you use storyboards instead of coding programmatically.. . Anyways, try typing this in the viewconroller, but first use textView closure and then inside the closure type this:  textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

which allows your text view to pop up.. . I hope it works out.. .